# load js file in express

Tags: node.js, express

I've created a node js program: data.js :location is controllers data.js

```
var myPythonScriptPath = 'script.py';

const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");
var pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);

var moduel= pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
console.log(message);
});

pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
   };

    console.log('finished');
});
```

I created an express framework: APP.JS:

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {

pyshell.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log(data.toString());
    res.write(data);
    res.end('end');
});
})

app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Application listening on port 4000!'));
```

I want to open data.js file in APP.JS file such that it can route to data.js file stored in controllers folder and display the data of data.js on server.

Answer (score 0):

Use module.exports to export any function in a file.

```
//server.js
var ctrl = require('./controllers/data.js');
app.get('/', ctrl.getData);





//controllers/data.js
var myPythonScriptPath = 'script.py';

const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");
var pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);


function getData(req, res){
    // do your pyShell activities here.
    // sends a message to the Python script via stdin
pyshell.send('hello');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
  console.log(message);
        res.send(message);

});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
  console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
  console.log('finished');
  console.log('finished');
});
}

module.exports = {
    getData: getData
}
```

Comment: " but it loaded the file without using "module.export" ".  Without using  module.exports also you are able to access getData function from server.js?

Comment: No sorry it didn't work...I made a mistake and ran old file in the same directory....can you please write complete code so I can see what mistakes I'm including as I'm unable to implement it. It would really be big help sir.